# Fetch data from mongodb with react and axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, use-effect

Good morning! I've been trying yesterday to fetch data from my mongodb. However with the code above I get the json in the console but imposible to put the json inside the state. Could you help me?. Thanks for all your answers. :)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from "axios"

function CreateUser() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fecthData = async () => {
            await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/users")
                .then(res => {
                    setCountries(res.data);
                    console.log(countries);
                });
        };
        fecthData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4">
                from user
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-8">
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {countries.map((country, index) => <li key={index}>{country.name}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CreateUser

/* const fecthData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/users");
    setUsers(res.data);
    console.log(res.data);
};
fecthData(); */
```

Comment: I would not expect to see the JSON in the console; countries doesn't have the value provided to setCountries until the next time the component is rendered. But it's unclear what the *problem* is here.

Comment: Try to log `countries` just after the useEffect.

Comment: Please don't mix promise chaining with async-await syntax. Use either one of them but not both at the same time. Also don't log the `countries` immediately after calling `setCountries()` because stats is updated asynchronously so logging `countries` will log an empty array. If you want to log the updated `countries` array, use another `useEffect` hook that executes whenever `countries` is updated. Alternatively, you could just log `res.data` instead of `countries`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
const x = countries.lenth ? countries[0].name : 'Loading...'

console.log(x)
```

You are facing this issue because `state` takes time to store the data, and before the data gets saved in the state the DOM renders itself.